# Regex replace between notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of values in a csv, which i'm trying to alter slightly using a REGEX search and replace using Notepad++. What I have contains the following examples:

```
Text,UK_BT.BT1.BT1 1,123
Text,UK_BT.BT11.BT11 1,123
Text,IE_text.text.text,123
```

What i'm wanting to do, is remove the text between first comma and last period, ***only*** where the line contains UK_BT. So the output would be:

```
Text,BT1 1,123
Text,BT11 1,123
Text,IE_text.text.text,123
```

Does anyone have any clues? Regex really isnt my strongpoint and generally gets forgotten after using it!
Thanks,

Comment: Why `Text,IE_text.text,123` becomes `Text,IE_text.text.text,123` ?

Comment: Typo, which has been fixed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what: `^(?=.*UK_BT.*)([^,]+,).*\.([^\.]+)$`

Replace with `\1\2`

**Explanation**

```
^             # Beginning of the line.
(?=.*UK_BT.*) # Must contain 'UK_BT' (positive look ahead, not capturing group, not character consuming).
(             # Beginning of the first group.
  [^,]+,      # Everything but ',' at least one time (+) followed by ',' (first ',').
)             # End of the first group.
.*            # Everything zero or more times.
\.            # A single '.'.
(             # Beginning of the second group.
 [^\.]+       # Everything but '.' at least one time (this in combination with '\.' allows to find the last '.').
)             # End of the second group.
$             # End of the line
```

`\1\2` allows to point to the first and second captured group.

Answer (score 0):

Try it next time you won't forget it...
Find what: `UK.+\d\.`
Replace with: `nothing`